# Issues on ios 13.7

Tags: mitmproxy

Followed all the steps, installed the certificate on ios 13.7 as a new profile, I still can't access any https sites via safari or any other app.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: What did you exactly do in this "all the steps"? A reference to this used tutorial would be helpful to understand what you did.

Comment: I started the proxy, set it on the networking config of the ipad. Downloaded the profile. Enabled Settings -> General ->About -> Enable Full Trust For Root Certificates on the new mitmproxy certificate. But when I try to navigate I get an error saying safari can not establish a secure connection. Logs show client connect/disconnect.

Comment: Just a note that on my macbook it works, only ipad 13.7 and 14.x are failing

Comment: You know that you have to accept the profile plus then enable the certificates from the profiles?

Comment: Yes and I did that on the first time. It's not working on ipad, tried on 14.1 and it does not work either, also tried on 4 different ipads all with the same result

Comment: The same situation for me. I can't use it for my iOS 14

Comment: same here on iOS 15.6 - iPhone 11 pro